# My Air conditioner is blowing hot on the left side and cold on the right

Tags: chevrolet, hvac, camaro

My air conditioning in my Camaro ss 2012 is blowing hot on the left side and cold on the right. Anyone knows what the problem could be??

Comment: Well everything is fine if you're getting hot air, but you must have a vent pipe unhooked, that'd be my guess, so your feeling the air from outside

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It's more than likely a blend door motor which is stuck or dead on the one side.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 This would require that the HVAC system has two blend doors (one of each side of the car, along with a separate cold air feed on each side) to make the hot/cold  adjustment. Have you seen such a system? A simpler design (seems more attractive to me, engineering-wise) would have the heated and unheated air streams join just downstream of the heater core, with a single blend door at the apex controlling airflow mix. I'd want to check for a loose vent pipe, as suggested by hello motto.

Comment: @David - That's the way most systems these days are designed ... if they have dual zone HVAC ... passenger and driver side is completely separate. I'm talking *a lot* of vehicles are setup this way.

Comment: Thank guys for giving me some clarity about the issue,I’ll check for the vent pipes first thing in the morning

Comment: Is my first time in this website and so far I gotta say is very helpful

Comment: @Paulster2 Ah! I didn't think of dual-zone heating. Thanks for the reality check.

Comment: @David is it the same for older models as well with central A/C controls ? I have a somewhat simliar issue - https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/64933/why-may-heating-gradually-stop-after-some-time-driving

Comment: @darune I don't know what "central A/C controls" means. If there's no ability to adjust heat differently for the driver and passenger, then I'd say the car has a single system for providing heat, and as you describe in the other thread, it's not working correctly. Because it works initially, and then fails, I think there's an obstruction in the plumbing which carries coolant to and through the heater core. I'd make sure all the heater hoses are free of internal obstructions, and that the heater core itself allows coolant to flow.