# Why may heating gradually stop after some time driving (and doesn't work in passenger side at all)?

Tags: ac, cooling-system, hvac, heater, head-gasket

This is a somewhat strange problem. Heating (in driver side) seems to work normal - after somewhere between 15-25 mins. driving or so, it gradually stops working. The warming in passenger side doesn't seem to warm at all (fans work though).

After rest, this behavior can be repeated without any changes done to the system.

The car have had a number of issues with the coolant system - including the head gasket replaced. Other repairs include a replaced hose, a tube and thermostat. Also "expansion bucket" was re-installed.

I think it may be loosing coolant near top somewhere, but seen as very very little or only sometimes. **UPDATE: I am now certain that it looses coolant 'somewhere' but haven't found the leak yet (still though seem as very little (in the magnitude of ½-1½ dl per day or after driving)).**

It doesn't seem build pressure quickly in the coolant (after one recent try - but not sure here)

Could it be that the top gasket (or something related) - is still an issue even after fix ? Or could it be a sensor defect ?

Can provide more information if needed.

Model is a Suzuki Liana/AERIO 2006

**Update:**

It doesn't matter what type of driving I do it is going to happend at some point (the exact timing im not sure about). It is somewhat cold weather right now where i live but not freezing (the end temperature just seems to match the outside environment - even when turned to the hottest). The controls is climate control type (simply select more or less).

Comment: Lets start by establishing the environment in which the car is driven as this could affect how the cooling system responds over a driving period. Could you describe where you are and what normal temperatures during these issues are? Also what kind of driving are you doing during these 15-20 minutes? Mostly constant speed highway driving, stop and go, etc. And, not trying to overload you with questions here, is the climate control in the car a manual style where you simply select more or less hot or is it temperature based? Sorry for all the questions.

Comment: It doesn't matter what type of driving I do it is going to happend at some point (the exact timing im not sure about). It is somewhat cold weather but not freezing (the end temperature seems to match the outside environment - even when turned to the hottest). It is climate control (simply select more or less).